How to build my own text-to-image or image-to-image with GAN or StableDiffusion and run locally?
When I say "build" is not from scratch of course, is get a model pre-trained, such like Stable Diffusion, and "train again" with another kind of dataset or change parameters to a specific purpose.
I know there's a lot of services on internet offering this kind of stuff, some free, freemium or paid. But we all know that there's a 'mystery' of what happen to the date we input in this tools.
I'd like to test run a version of StableDiffusion locally optimized for some tasks like:
e.g
Text-to-Image -> For 2d game arts
Image-to-Image -> for apply filters such like aging, change colors, hide skin imperfections or even recreate a image in a differente scenario, like take a photo of yours on the beach and recreate on an office.
If you can provide links, articles and tutorials of this process would be great.
